# What's the connection between finite type manifolds and the dimention of their de Rham cohomology groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I'm reading "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" recently.
Here comes a nature question to me:
Dose any connected manifold which has a finite dimensional de Rham cohomology group admit a finite good cover?

Comment: At first I thought the 3-dimensional [Whitehead manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) might be a counterexample, but then I recalled a [theorem of Gabai](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jtopol/jtr010).

Comment: There is also a paper of Garity, Repovš and Wright entitled *Contractible 3-manifolds and the double 3-space property* (Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 370 (2018), no. 3, 2039–2055) which gives uncountably many contractible 3-manifolds that do not have good covers of cardinality 2.